# How to open links from excel in just one tab of Internet Explorer

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

When running this macro code, it will open the links at row A in Internet Explorer in different windows. What should be edited so it will open in just one browser and just one tab.

```
Sub OpenInAnotherBrowser()
Dim iePath As String
Dim browser As String
Dim URL As String
Dim useIE As Boolean
Dim rowInd As Integer

iePath = "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
useIE = True

If Dir(iePath) = "" Then pathie = "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"


If Dir(iePath) = "" Then
    If MsgBox("IE Not Found, Open with default browser?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        useIE = False
    End If
End If

rowInd = 1

Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(rowInd, 1)) 'loop mo until empty cell mag point

    URL = Cells(rowInd, 1).Value

    If useIE Then
        Shell """" & iePath & """" & URL, vbHide
    Else
        Application.FollowHyperlink URL
    End If

    rowInd = rowInd + 1 'Iterate here
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: @Carlosng01, 1 quick question - In one internet browser - 

You want to open multiple URLs in different tabs or in 1 tab?

Comment: one Internet Explorer. Open all the links in 1 tab, one by one :)

Comment: It is like I will open A1 in browser tab1, wait for it to fully load, then open A2 link in browser tab1, wait for it to fully load, and so on.